# To store million keys of million length which will be better red black tree or radix tree?

Tags: java, red-black-tree, radix-tree

I want to store multiple keys(String) of million length with their objects associated with it. Such that I have to insert in the data structure(rbtree or radix tree) very frequently and have to search quite a low number of time as compared to insert. Any reccommendations will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since insertion is your primary concern, then you should use a red-black tree because its insertion time complexity is logarithmically in the input size, that is `O(k*log n)` with `log` being base 2 logarithm, `k` is the size or length of each input and `n` is the amount of inputs. The radix tree's insert is linear in the size `k` of each input and in the amount `n` of inputs , that is `O(k*n)`, which is worse than for red-black trees, unless **many** of the string keys share **sufficiently long prefixes** in order to transform `n` in a sub-logarithmic expression of `n`.

Comment: But won't be the insertion time of red black will be O(k log n) where k is the length of the key in each node which is of average length a million and worst case of radix tree will be O(k).

Comment: @AnuragSingla The same argument can be used to say that in the radix tree the complexity would be O(kn) where n is the amount of inputs. It ultimately depends on the asker's specific situation. And also note that he/she **will** have to search the tree, even if its fewer times compared to inserting in it.

Comment: How will be the complexity of Radix tree will be O(kn).Can you please that again ? And I've edited the question the key to be inserted are also now in millions.Thank you.

Comment: @AnuragSingla Assume you have n strings you want to store in a radix tree. The main feature of a radix tree (also know as prefix tree/trie) is that it uses common prefixes among the strings (and substrings obtained from iteratively removing such prefixes) to perform insertion, if no common prefixes among the strings are found, you end up having to perform n insertions. A common prefix is `re` in *real* and *remote*. Got a clearer picture now?

Comment: @AnuragSingla Wikipedia has an introductory article about radix trees at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree although it has a few omissions about its run-time analysis and implementation details, it has a nice picture with an example where you'll realize the importance of common prefixes.

Comment: @AnuragSingla You should realize that when no strings have common prefixes a radix tree becomes an array of individual and unconnected branches, thus defeating its own purpose and uselfunnes and attaining the worst case complexity of O(kn). Before you ask if it becomes an array then why insert is not constant at the tail its because you'll still be doing node checks and comparisons.

Comment: Thank You for your time.Now I have a clearer understanding of these two data structures.